# form is not reloading current page

Tags: php, forms

I've got a state machine in "currentpage.php". I'm trying to call the file and prep the data in the first state. The second state I want to display information and allow changes to be made. And finally the last state will be to interpret the data and save it off.

The following code is from the second state but when "Save" is pressed the page doesn't reload. Why and what can I do to make it work?

```
<form method="post" action="currentpage.php"></form>
<div id="content">
<div id="fields">
    <?php echo '<textarea name="textarea" style="width:100%;height:100%;" >'.$_SESSION["textarea"].'</textarea>'; ?>
</div>
<div id="instructions">
    <input type="submit" id="" value="Save"></input>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove

```
</form>
```

So change

```
<form method="post" action="currentpage.php"></form>
```

on this

```
<form method="post" action="currentpage.php">
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks guys... it's like that ever illusive missing ';'. I never noticed the closing tag was there.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the form with nothing inside it, remove the closing form tag so it looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="currentpage.php">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="fields">
            <?php echo '<textarea name="textarea" style="width:100%;height:100%;" >'.$_SESSION["textarea"].'</textarea>'; ?>
        </div>
        <div id="instructions">
            <input type="submit" id="" value="Save"></input>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```